# R Plotly set custom colors for bar chart

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I've got a `plotly` bar chart in my Shiny app, and I'd like to set specific colors each column in the resulting bar chart.

```
#Here's some reproducible data
df=data.frame(Month=c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun"),Criteria1=c(10,15,20,15,7,6),Criteria2=c(3,8,5,7,9,10),Criteria3=c(11,18,14,9,3,1))

#Plot

colNames <- names(df)[-1] #Month is the first column

# Here is where I set the colors for each `Criteria`, assuming that the order of colors follows the same order as the factor levels of the `Criteria`.

p <- plotly::plot_ly(marker=list(colors=c('#CC1480', '#FF9673', '#E1C8B4')))

for(trace in colNames){
  p <- p %>% plotly::add_trace(data = df, x = ~Month, y = as.formula(paste0("~`", trace, "`")), name = trace, type = "bar")
}

p %>% 
  layout(title = "Trend Over Time",showlegend = FALSE,
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list (title = "Monthly Count of QoL Tweets"))
```

However the resulting plot does not show any of the colors I specify.

What am I doing incorrectly? Any pointers would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your input data or some mock data?

Comment: I've edited my question to include some reproducible data.

Comment: You can't reference `df` as `df()`

Comment: Sorry I forget to remove the (). However it still doesn't show me the colors in the order I would like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign your colors to a vector:

```
colors <- c('#CC1480', '#FF9673', '#E1C8B4')
```

and then add the traces in a slightly modified loop.

```
p <- plotly::add_trace(p, 
                       x = df$Month, 
                       y = df[,trace], 
                       marker = list(color = colors[[match(trace, colNames)]]), 
                       name = trace, 
                       type = "bar")
}
```

which will give you the following graph

### [image]

**Complete code**

```
library("plotly")
df=data.frame(Month=c("Jan", "Feb","Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"),
              Criteria1 = c(10, 15,20,15,7,6),
              Criteria2 = c(3, 8, 5, 7, 9, 10),
              Criteria3 = c(11, 18, 14, 9, 3, 1))

colNames <- names(df)[-1] #Month is the first column
colors <- c('#CC1480', '#FF9673', '#E1C8B4')
p <- plotly::plot_ly()

#colNames = c('Criteria1')
for(trace in colNames){
  p <- plotly::add_trace(p, 
                         x = df$Month, 
                         y = df[,trace], 
                         marker = list(color = colors[[match(trace, colNames)]]), 
                         name = trace, 
                         type = "bar")
}

p
```

Answer (score 11):

I don't think loop is neccessary here, the following provides as well more control over choosing the color for specific levels when `df` is melted, the individual levels `Criteria1`, `Criteria2`, `Criteria3`

```
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)

#Yout data.frame
df <- data.frame(Month = c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun"),
                 Criteria1 = c(10,15,20,15,7,6),
                 Criteria2 = c(3,8,5,7,9,10),
                 Criteria3 = c(11,18,14,9,3,1))

melt(df, id.vars = 'Month') %>% plot_ly(x = ~Month, y = ~value, type = 'bar', 
  color = ~variable,
  colors = c(Criteria1 = '#CC1480', Criteria2 = '#FF9673', Criteria3 = '#E1C8B4'))
```

[image]