# How to change colours of a group bar plot?

Tags: r, plotly

i am fairly new to R and I am having trouble changing the colours of a grouped bar plot. My code that I have inputted is the following:

```
library(plotly)
Samples <- c("1" , "2" , "P3")
D0 <- c(5.55, 5.605, 5.414)
D28 <- c(5.642, 1.658, 5.551)
data <- data.frame(Samples, D0, D28)
p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Samples, y = ~D0, type = 'bar' , name = 'D0') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~D28, name = 'D28') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Concentration (mM)'), barmode = 'group')
p
```

this is the resulting graph. i am interested in just changing the colour of the blue and the colour of the orange and to keep the same format they are coloured in (first bar plot=one colour and second bar plot=another colour). I have tried a different code but this results in all of them getting coloured with the same colour. Does anyone know which code to use to get what I want? Thanks in advance!
[image: Grouped Bar Plot]

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771511/r-plotly-set-custom-colors-for-bar-chart ?

Comment: using the marker=... option should allow you to change color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to specify the color for each separately, since you are calling D0 in `plot_ly` and D28 in `add_trace`.

```r
plot_ly(data, x = ~Samples, y = ~D0, type = 'bar' , name = 'D0', color = I("black")) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~D28, name = 'D28', color = I("yellow")) %>%
    layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Concentration (mM)'), barmode = 'group')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `marker` option in `plotly` to have your custom color for each plots:

Below is the modified code:

```
library(plotly)
Samples <- c("1" , "2" , "P3")
D0 <- c(5.55, 5.605, 5.414)
D28 <- c(5.642, 1.658, 5.551)
data <- data.frame(Samples, D0, D28)
p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~Samples, y = ~D0, type = 'bar' , name = 'D0',marker = list(color=c('green'))) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~D28, name = 'D28',marker = list(color=c('red'))) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Concentration (mM)'), barmode = 'group')

p
```

Output:

[image]